# Event Binding in Backbone.Marionette context

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bind, underscore.js, marionette

I am wondering why `_.bindAll(this, ['onSortRemove']);` in the following code (1) rises the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method
>   'resetItemViewContainer'

To get things working I need to implement the following code `_.bindAll(this);`.

My question is: should `_.bindAll(this, ['onSortRemove']);` be enough? if not, why?

---

(1)

```
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, ['onSortRemove']); // it does not work
        _.bindAll(this); // it works
     }

    onSortRemove: function () {
        setTimeout(this.render, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error

```
initialize: function () {
  _.bindAll(this, 'onSortRemove'); // <- no array wrapper
}
```

The documentation's syntax of `[*methodnames]` is not saying "wrap this in an array". That's old-school documentation style to say "method names is optional, it can be zero or more arguments, comma-delimited".